# Using batch script to find filename and run a convert command using that filename

Tags: batch-file, ssconvert

I'm attempting to grab a text file from a folder for conversion to .xls using `ssconvert`. Currently I have:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do set FileName=%%~na 
ssconvert %FileName%.txt %FileName%.xls
```

However this results in this being run:

```
ssconvert thefile .txt thefile .xls
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

How would I get rid of the space between the `FileName` variable and the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do  ssconvert %%~na.txt %%~na.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with `%%~na` needing to be just `%%a`.

Comment: I had a space in the batch script after ~na , making this completely my fault! Cheers anyway